# Methods using methods in python

Tags: python, oop, methods

I know there are many questions that touch upon this area, but none have clearly answered the problem I'm facing (or perhaps I'm just really thick).

So I'm transferring functional python code to OOP python, and I have some code

```
class fake_class:
    def __init__(self, data_type=None):
        if data_type is None:
            self.data_type = ""
        else:
            self.data_type = data_type 

    def printToLog(x='', *args):
        if args:
            x = x.format(*args)
        else:
            x = str(x)
        logFile.write(x)
        logFile.write('\n')
        print(x)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

   def main(self):
        self.printToLog('this is just an example, for some fake code')


f = fake_class('data-xml-435')
# please appreciate that the full code is over 500 lines 
# long that has been edited down for the sake of readability
```

I need the main method to be able to call other methods in the class, but no matter what I do, I cannot manage to allow it to do so. I have made printToLog into a classmethod, I have tried different ways of instantiating the fake_class, calling and all to no avail. The program complains that it doesn't know what printToLog is, what self is or what fake_class is!

So how might I call a method with another method within Python?

Comment: You have to fix your indentation. 4 spaces per level is best.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. `main` should not be a method, it has nothing to do with the class.

Comment: try `f.printToLog()`

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, because it's unheard of for classes to have main methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

does not make any sense with class. You just don't need them.

With that removed, you have to call `main` explicitly using the object you created.

```
f = fake_class('data-xml-435')
f.main() # or f.printToLog(with arguments) whichever is exciting you!
```

Again, `printToLog` is function of class, so you need a `self`:

```
def printToLog(self, x='', *args):
    if args:
        x = x.format(*args)
    else:
        x = str(x)
    logFile.write(x)
    logFile.write('\n')
    print(x)
```